# Cube inscribed in a sphere coloured in blue (10%) and red (90%).

Tags: probability

10% of the surface of the sphere is coloured in blue, rest is coloured in red. Show that no matter how the colours are distributed, you can inscribe cube into this sphere in a way that all of the vertices of the cube are red.

I don't even know how to start, so any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you measure the percentages? The set of blue points might be non-measurable.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for all point in the sphere there is only one inscribe cube in the sphere that has this point as a vertex.

Divide the sphere in 8 equal part $S_1$ to $S_8$ and consider the sphere $S'$ with the same division $S_1'$ to $S_8'$ but where the colouring changes in the following way: all points in $S'_1$ to $S'_7$ are red, and the point in $S'_8$ are blue if and only if one of the vertex of the associated cube was blue in $S$.

I let you conclude from here...